# FIleSystemWatcher.Created how does it work?

Tags: vb.net, filesystemwatcher

I am working on a project that will copy files to a database every time something is added to a specific directory. Now the program works fine when I'm testing with a small set of data but I was wondering if someone could explain how the FileSystemWatcher.Created event work.

My main concern is when I use this on a larger scale the program may slow down when it handles 100,000+ files.

If this is an issue could anyone explain if there is some sort of workaround to polling the original folder, lets call that "C:\folder", and maybe poll a temp folder instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested the watcher with 100,000 files.  However, in most cases you should not have so many files in a folder awaiting processing.  I recommend a structure like

```
C:\folder
C:\folder\processing
C:\folder\archive
C:\folder\error
```

As soon as you begin working on a given file, move it into `processing`.  If you successfully process it, move the file again to `archive`.  If there is an error while processing a file, instead move it into `error`.

This will make it easier for you to keep the files organized and diagnose problems that occur in production.

With that file structure, you will not run into issues with large numbers of files in the folder you are watching, unless you receive files in incredibly large bursts compared to the speed with which they can be moved into the processing state.

Comment: Thank you, I'm fairly new at developing for large scale projects such as this one. Thanks for the tip for future projects